# employee_data.employees was not found in location US

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I tried reference the name as it is with the project but that did not help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because your dataset location and query settings location is different. First check the location of your dataset . To check the dataset location you can click on 3 dots beside that dataset and click on open in current tab or new tab or split tab whichever option you like

click on 3 dots beside that dataset

[image]

open in current tab

[image]

and check the location value.

or

open Cloud Shell and execute below command

```
bq show --format=prettyjson how-to-use-bigquery-347718:employee_data | grep location
```

Then click on that 3 dots besides Run

[image]

and Open Query settings and set the location to same location as your dataset and save that settings

[image]

Comment: Thanks @james-z for formatting the answer.